# Invalid Column Index Exception while hibernate update

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to update values using hibernate update. it throws the following exception

```
Jul 07, 2014 2:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/apld] threw exception [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [EITEMDIV1#7]] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setIntInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setInt(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:209)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setInt(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2823)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2806)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3191)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at com.chainsys.fwk.db.DynamicSession.flush(DynamicSession.java:420)
    at com.chainsys.fwk.db.DynamicSession.close(DynamicSession.java:138)
    at com.chainsys.dynui.impl.DynaPageDAOImpl.create(DynaPageDAOImpl.java:39)
    at com.chainsys.dynui.handler.DynaPageHandler.create(DynaPageHandler.java:61)
    at com.chainsys.dynui.web.action.DynaPageAction.create(DynaPageAction.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.chainsys.fwk.web.util.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I'm passing map to merge method with entity name. my map has all values,hibernate run the select query and compares the changed value to phrase update statement. don't know how it internally set the values to it.

**Hibernate Select Query:**

```
    SELECT eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMNAMEID      AS ITEMNAME1_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMNAME             AS ITEMNAME2_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DESCRIPTION          AS DESCRIPT3_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WAREHOUSENAME        AS WAREHOUS4_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WAREHOUSENAMEID      AS WAREHOUS5_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMTYPE             AS ITEMTYPE6_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMTYPEID           AS ITEMTYPE7_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MAKEBUY              AS MAKEBUY8_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.UNITOFMEASURE        AS UNITOFME9_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.UNITOFMEASUREID      AS UNITOFM10_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.NATUREOFITEM         AS NATUREO11_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CURRENCY             AS CURRENC12_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CURRENCYID           AS CURRENC13_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.RECEIPTMETHOD        AS RECEIPT14_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.EXCISETARRIF         AS EXCISET15_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.EXCISETARRIFID       AS EXCISET16_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMLOCATION         AS ITEMLOC17_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ACTIVE               AS ACTIVE18_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PACKINGITEM          AS PACKING19_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PACKINGITEMID        AS PACKING20_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.BOMITEMTYPE          AS BOMITEM21_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMTEMPLATE         AS ITEMTEM22_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMTEMPLATEID       AS ITEMTEM23_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ASSETCATEGORY        AS ASSETCA24_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PLANNINGMETHOD       AS PLANNIN25_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.FORECASTLEVEL        AS FORECAS26_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PURLEADTIME          AS PURLEAD27_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MANLEADTIME          AS MANLEAD28_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MINMAXMIN            AS MINMAXM29_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MINMAXMAX            AS MINMAXM30_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MINORDER             AS MINORDE31_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MAXORDER             AS MAXORDE32_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.REORDER              AS REORDER33_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PLANNINGNAME         AS PLANNIN34_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PLANNINGNAMEID       AS PLANNIN35_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DEMANDTIME           AS DEMANDT36_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CONSIDEROLD          AS CONSIDE37_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WEEKDATETYPE         AS WEEKDAT38_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MONTHDATETYPE        AS MONTHDA39_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.AVAILABILITYCHECK    AS AVAILAB40_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.FIXEDLOTMULTIPLIER   AS FIXEDLO41_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCEWARE           AS SOURCEW42_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCEWAREID         AS SOURCEW43_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUB            AS SOURCES44_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUBID          AS SOURCES45_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUPPLIER       AS SOURCES46_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUPPLIERID     AS SOURCES47_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUPSITE        AS SOURCES48_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SOURCESUPSITEID      AS SOURCES49_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DESSUPINV            AS DESSUPI50_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DESSUPINVID          AS DESSUPI51_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.STDUNITPRICE         AS STDUNIT52_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DEFAULTSUBINV        AS DEFAULT53_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DEFAULTSUBINVID      AS DEFAULT54_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.LOTCONTROLLED        AS LOTCONT55_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SECLOTCONTROLLED     AS SECLOTC56_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SEARIALNUMBER        AS SEARIAL57_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SNPREFIX             AS SNPREFI58_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.PHYINV               AS PHYINV59_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CYCLECOUNT           AS CYCLECO60_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ABCCLASS             AS ABCCLAS61_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.INTERCLASS           AS INTERCL62_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ABCCLASSPOP          AS ABCCLAS63_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ABCCLASSPOPID        AS ABCCLAS64_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SHELFLIFE            AS SHELFLI65_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SALESORDERITEM       AS SALESOR66_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.COMPLIMENT           AS COMPLIM67_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.MANPARTNO            AS MANPART68_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SUPPARTNO            AS SUPPART69_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.HANDLIINGINSTRUCTION AS HANDLII70_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.STORAGEINSTRUCTION   AS STORAGE71_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WEIGHT               AS WEIGHT72_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WEIGHTUOM            AS WEIGHTU73_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.LENGTH               AS LENGTH74_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.WIDTH                AS WIDTH75_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.HEIGHT               AS HEIGHT76_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ATTRIBUTEUOM         AS ATTRIBU77_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.DIMENSION            AS DIMENSI78_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.ALTERNATENAME        AS ALTERNA79_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.FRENCHCOUNT          AS FRENCHC80_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CF20                 AS CF81_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CF40                 AS CF82_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.TWISTPERINCH         AS TWISTPE83_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.FIXEDEFFICIENCY      AS FIXEDEF84_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.SITRANORMS           AS SITRANO85_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.COMPANYNORMS         AS COMPANY86_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CFPOWERHOUSE         AS CFPOWER87_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CFBLOWROOM           AS CFBLOWR88_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CFCARDING            AS CFCARDI89_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CFPREPARATORY        AS CFPREPA90_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.CFSPINNING           AS CFSPINN91_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.EYCEFFICIENCY        AS EYCEFFI92_17_1_,
  eitemdiv1x0_.NONEYCEFFICIENCY     AS NONEYCE93_17_1_,
  itemrevisi1_.ITEMID               AS ITEMID4_17_3_,
  itemrevisi1_.REVISIONID           AS REVISION1_45_3_,
  itemrevisi1_.REVISIONID           AS REVISION1_45_0_,
  itemrevisi1_.REVISIONFLAG         AS REVISION2_45_0_,
  itemrevisi1_.REVISION             AS REVISION3_45_0_,
  itemrevisi1_.ITEMID               AS ITEMID4_45_0_,
  itemrevisi1_.STARTDATE            AS STARTDAT5_45_0_,
  itemrevisi1_.ENDDATE              AS ENDDATE6_45_0_
FROM EITEMDIV1 eitemdiv1x0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEMREVISIONDIV itemrevisi1_
ON eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMNAMEID   =itemrevisi1_.ITEMID
WHERE eitemdiv1x0_.ITEMNAMEID=?
```

**Hibernate Prepared Update Query:**

```
    UPDATE EITEMDIV1
SET ITEMLOCATION      =?,
  ITEMTEMPLATE        =?,
  ASSETCATEGORY       =?,
  PURLEADTIME         =?,
  MANLEADTIME         =?,
  MINMAXMIN           =?,
  MINMAXMAX           =?,
  MINORDER            =?,
  MAXORDER            =?,
  REORDER             =?,
  PLANNINGNAME        =?,
  DEMANDTIME          =?,
  FIXEDLOTMULTIPLIER  =?,
  SOURCEWARE          =?,
  SOURCESUB           =?,
  SOURCESUPPLIER      =?,
  SOURCESUPSITE       =?,
  DESSUPINV           =?,
  STDUNITPRICE        =?,
  DEFAULTSUBINV       =?,
  SNPREFIX            =?,
  ABCCLASSPOP         =?,
  SHELFLIFE           =?,
  MANPARTNO           =?,
  SUPPARTNO           =?,
  HANDLIINGINSTRUCTION=?,
  STORAGEINSTRUCTION  =?,
  WEIGHT              =?,
  WEIGHTUOM           =?,
  LENGTH              =?,
  WIDTH               =?,
  HEIGHT              =?,
  ATTRIBUTEUOM        =?,
  DIMENSION           =?,
  ALTERNATENAME       =?,
  FRENCHCOUNT         =?,
  CF20                =?,
  CF40                =?,
  TWISTPERINCH        =?,
  FIXEDEFFICIENCY     =?,
  SITRANORMS          =?,
  COMPANYNORMS        =?,
  CFPOWERHOUSE        =?,
  CFBLOWROOM          =?,
  CFCARDING           =?,
  CFPREPARATORY       =?,
  CFSPINNING          =?,
  EYCEFFICIENCY       =?,
  NONEYCEFFICIENCY    =?
WHERE ITEMNAMEID      =?
```

**My Entity XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class entity-name="EITEMDIV1" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="itemNameId" type="int" column="ITEMNAMEID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">EItemSeq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="itemName" column="ITEMNAME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="string" length="200"/>
    <property name="warehouseName" column="WAREHOUSENAME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="warehouseNameId" column="WAREHOUSENAMEID" type="int"/>
    <property name="itemType" column="ITEMTYPE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="itemTypeId" column="ITEMTYPEID" type="int"/>
    <property name="makeBuy" column="MAKEBUY" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="unitOfMeasure" column="UNITOFMEASURE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="unitOfMeasureId" column="UNITOFMEASUREID" type="int"/>
    <property name="natureOfItem" column="NATUREOFITEM" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="currency" column="CURRENCY" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="currencyId" column="CURRENCYID" type="int"/>
    <property name="receiptMethod" column="RECEIPTMETHOD" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="exciseTarrif" column="EXCISETARRIF" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="exciseTarrifId" column="EXCISETARRIFID" type="int"/>
    <property name="itemLocation" column="ITEMLOCATION" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="active" column="ACTIVE" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="packingItem" column="PACKINGITEM" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="packingItemId" column="PACKINGITEMID" type="int"/>
    <property name="bomItemType" column="BOMITEMTYPE" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="itemTemplate" column="ITEMTEMPLATE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="itemTemplateId" column="ITEMTEMPLATEID" type="int"/>
    <property name="assetCategory" column="ASSETCATEGORY" type="string" length="100"/>
<!--EItemDiv1-->    <property name="planningMethod" column="PLANNINGMETHOD" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="forecastLevel" column="FORECASTLEVEL" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="purLeadTime" column="PURLEADTIME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="manLeadTime" column="MANLEADTIME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="minMaxMin" column="MINMAXMIN" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="minMaxMax" column="MINMAXMAX" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="minOrder" column="MINORDER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="maxOrder" column="MAXORDER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="reorder" column="REORDER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="planningName" column="PLANNINGNAME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="planningNameId" column="PLANNINGNAMEID" type="int"/>
    <property name="demandTimeFence" column="DEMANDTIME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="considerOld" column="CONSIDEROLD" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="weekDataType" column="WEEKDATETYPE" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="monthDateType" column="MONTHDATETYPE" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="availabilityCheck" column="AVAILABILITYCHECK" type="string" length="100"/>
<!--Planning--> <property name="fixedLotMultiplier" column="FIXEDLOTMULTIPLIER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sourceWare" column="SOURCEWARE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sourceWareId" column="SOURCEWAREID" type="int"/>
    <property name="sourceSub" column="SOURCESUB" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sourceSubId" column="SOURCESUBID" type="int"/>
    <property name="sourceSupplier" column="SOURCESUPPLIER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sourceSupplierId" column="SOURCESUPPLIERID" type="int"/>
    <property name="sourceSupSite" column="SOURCESUPSITE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sourceSupSiteId" column="SOURCESUPSITEID" type="int"/>
    <property name="desSupInv" column="DESSUPINV" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="desSupInvId" column="DESSUPINVID" type="int"/>
    <property name="stdUnitPrice" column="STDUNITPRICE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="defaultSubInv" column="DEFAULTSUBINV" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="defaultSubInvId" column="DEFAULTSUBINVID" type="int"/>
<!--Sourcing--> <property name="lotControlled" column="LOTCONTROLLED" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="secLotControlled" column="SECLOTCONTROLLED" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="serialNumber" column="SEARIALNUMBER" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="snPrefix" column="SNPREFIX" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="phyInv" column="PHYINV" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="cycleCount" column="CYCLECOUNT" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="abcClass" column="ABCCLASS" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="interClass" column="INTERCLASS" type="string" length="10"/>
    <property name="abcClassPop" column="ABCCLASSPOP" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="abcClassPopId" column="ABCCLASSPOPID" type="int"/>
    <property name="shelfLife" column="SHELFLIFE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="salesOrderItem" column="SALESORDERITEM" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="compliment" column="COMPLIMENT" type="string" length="10"/>
<!--Controls--> <property name="manPartNo" column="MANPARTNO" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="supPartNo" column="SUPPARTNO" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="handlingInstruction" column="HANDLIINGINSTRUCTION" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="storageInstruction" column="STORAGEINSTRUCTION" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="weight" column="WEIGHT" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="weightUOM" column="WEIGHTUOM" type="string" length="100"/>
<!--ItemAttributes-->   <property name="length" column="LENGTH" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="width" column="WIDTH" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="height" column="HEIGHT" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="attributeUOM" column="ATTRIBUTEUOM" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="dimension" column="DIMENSION" type="string" length="100"/>
<!--Phy.Attributes-->   <property name="alternateName" column="ALTERNATENAME" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="frenchCount" column="FRENCHCOUNT" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cf20" column="CF20" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cf40" column="CF40" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="twist" column="TWISTPERINCH" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="fixedEfficiency" column="FIXEDEFFICIENCY" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="sitranorms" column="SITRANORMS" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="companyNorms" column="COMPANYNORMS" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cfPowerHouse" column="CFPOWERHOUSE" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cfBlowRoom" column="CFBLOWROOM" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cfCarding" column="CFCARDING" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cfPreparatory" column="CFPREPARATORY" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="cfSpinning" column="CFSPINNING" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="eycEfficiency" column="EYCEFFICIENCY" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="nonEYCEFFICIENCY" column="NONEYCEFFICIENCY" type="string" length="100"/>
<!--CountData-->    <set lazy="false" name="itemRevisionList" table="ITEMREVISIONDIV" cascade="all" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="ITEMID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ITEMREVISIONDIV"/>
    </set>
<!--ItemRevision--></class>

<class entity-name="ITEMREVISIONDIV" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="revisionId" type="int" column="REVISIONID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">ItemRevisionSeq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="revisionFlag" column="REVISIONFLAG" type="string" length="1"/>
    <property name="revision" column="REVISION" type="string" length="100"/>
    <property name="itemId" column="ITEMID" type="int"/>
    <property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE" type="date"/>
    <property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE" type="date"/>
<!--ItemRevisionDiv--></class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

i don't have any clue to deal with this problem.

If anyone face this problem kindly help me.

Comment: post your model/entity classes. Hibernate prints SQL queries on console which may have the root cause.

Comment: Hi @NikhilTalreja, I've post my entity and printed sql queries.

Comment: Where is the code where you are setting values to your prepared statement?

Comment: i'm passing value as map.

Comment: Map<String, Object> map = new SpringBeanUtils().populateDynamicDTOObjectToMap(object);
            dbSession = HibernateUtils.getDynamicSession(new ByteArrayInputStream(dynaPageVO.getEntityMapping()));
            trans = dbSession.beginTransaction();
            object = dbSession.merge(dynaPageVO.getEntityName(), map);

Comment: Is this exception seen during reading from result set?